# Firebase registering device to multiple topics for WEB notifications

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending fcm notifications.
Now I want to register user to multiple topics in one request, how can I achieve that?

I have read the documentation but I have not found any documentation for that? 
Also what is the limit of number of topics for a single device after which it starts displaying TOO_MANY_TOPICS errors?

Answer (score 1):

Usually there should be no limits for subscriptions and topics (see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging). I personally go with a foreach loop if there are 20-30 topics to send for one user.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API to subscribe to multiple topics in one go. You'll have to [call the API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/topic-messaging#subscribe_the_client_app_to_a_topic) separately for each topic. As the documentation says, this call needs to be made from a server or otherwise trusted environment.

I'd take this approach up to a few dozen topics. If you need more than that, consider creating some broader topics. For example: many apps have a topic called `all` that they *also* send all messages to. That way people that want *all* messages, can subscribe to the `all` topic, instead of to each individual topic.